# Hashmaps getting overwritten, though new maps are created each iteration

Tags: java

I have this piece of code, where i'm fetching some data in a database (mysql), and storing it in a multidimensional hashmap. But the "programs" part is the same in every iteration, though i AM creating a new hashmap every iteration..

It's the "idProgram" hashmap causing the problem, i think ;s

Here is the code:

```
public static String epg() {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst2 = null;
    ResultSet rs2 = null;
    Date dNow = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMMdd");
    String time = ft.format(dNow).toString();
    String json = "[";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + main_server.ipSQL + ":" + main_server.portSQL + "/" + main_server.dbExtra;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, main_server.userSQL, main_server.passwordSQL);
        pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT idChannel, channelName, logoPath, macro FROM channel");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        while (rs.next()) { 
            LinkedHashMap<String, Object> channels = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
            LinkedHashMap<Integer,Object> idProgram = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Object>();
            channels.put("idChannel", rs.getString(1));
            channels.put("channelName", rs.getString(2));
            channels.put("logoPath", rs.getString(3));
            channels.put("macro", rs.getString(4));
            pst2 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT idProgram, title, start, stop, category, episodeNumber FROM program WHERE start LIKE '"+time+"%'");
            rs2 = pst2.executeQuery();
            while (rs2.next()) { 
                LinkedHashMap<String, Object> channels2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
                int duration = Integer.parseInt(rs2.getString(4).substring(8, 12)) - Integer.parseInt(rs2.getString(3).substring(8, 12));
                channels2.put("title", StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(rs2.getString(2)));
                channels2.put("category", StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(rs2.getString(5)));
                channels2.put("episodeNumber", rs2.getString(6));
                channels2.put("start", rs2.getLong(4));
                channels2.put("duration", duration);
                idProgram.put(rs2.getInt(1), channels2);
            }  
            channels.put("programs", idProgram);
            json = json + gson.toJson(channels) + ",";
        }  
        json = json.substring(0, json.length() - 1) + "]";
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(sql.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (pst != null) {
                pst.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(sql.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"));
        out.write(json);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return json;
}
```

**EDIT:**

This code outputs:

```
[
{
"idChannel": "1",
"channelName": "DR1 HD",
"logoPath": "/media/channel_logo/1.jpg",
"macro": "TV,1,ENTER",
"programs": {
  "55483": {
    "title": "Drivhusdrømme",
    "category": "documentary, serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .2/6. ",
    "start": 20130505065500,
    "duration": 30
  },
  "55484": {
    "title": "Der er noget i luften",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .10/320. ",
    "start": 20130505072000,
    "duration": 65
  },
  "55485": {
    "title": "Der er noget i luften",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .11/320. ",
    "start": 20130505075000,
    "duration": 30
  },
  "55486": {
    "title": "Der er noget i luften",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .12/320. ",
    "start": 20130505081500,
    "duration": 65
  },
  "55487": {
    "title": "Der er noget i luften",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .13/320. ",
    "start": 20130505084000,
    "duration": 25
  },
  "55488": {
    "title": "Der er noget i luften",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .14/320. ",
    "start": 20130505091000,
    "duration": 70
  },
  "55489": {
    "title": "Downton Abbey III",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .7/10. ",
    "start": 20130505101500,
    "duration": 105
  },
  "55490": {
    "title": "Downton Abbey III",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .8/10. ",
    "start": 20130505110500,
    "duration": 90
  },
  "55491": {
    "title": "Kyst til kyst - Østjyllands kyst",
    "category": "entertainment, serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .2/8. ",
    "start": 20130505120500,
    "duration": 100
  },
  "55492": {
    "title": "OBS",
    "category": "news, serie",
    "start": 20130505121000,
    "duration": 5
  },
  "55493": {
    "title": "BingoBoxen",
    "category": "entertainment, serie",
    "start": 20130505122500,
    "duration": 15
  },
  "55494": {
    "title": "General Custers sidste kamp",
    "category": "movie",
    "start": 20130505144000,
    "duration": 215
  },
  "55495": {
    "title": "For godt til at være sandt",
    "category": "entertainment, serie",
    "start": 20130505150000,
    "duration": 60
  },
  "55496": {
    "title": "Miss Marple: Den gustne hest",
    "category": "movie",
    "start": 20130505163000,
    "duration": 130
  },
  "55497": {
    "title": "HåndboldSøndag: Team Tvis Holstebro-Metz Handball (k), direkte",
    "category": "sport",
    "start": 20130505183000,
    "duration": 200
  },
  "55498": {
    "title": "TV AVISEN  med Sporten og Vejret",
    "category": "news, serie",
    "start": 20130505190000,
    "duration": 70
  },
  "55499": {
    "title": "Menneskets planet",
    "category": "documentary, serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .7/8. ",
    "start": 20130505194500,
    "duration": 45
  },
  "55500": {
    "title": "Bag om Menneskets planet",
    "category": "documentary, serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .7/8. ",
    "start": 20130505200000,
    "duration": 55
  }
}
},{
"idChannel": "2",
"channelName": "TV2 HD",
"logoPath": "/media/channel_logo/2.jpg",
"macro": "TV,2,ENTER",
"programs": {
  "55483": {
    "title": "Drivhusdrømme",
    "category": "documentary, serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .2/6. ",
    "start": 20130505065500,
    "duration": 30
  },
  "55484": {
    "title": "Der er noget i luften",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .10/320. ",
    "start": 20130505072000,
    "duration": 65
  },
  "55485": {
    "title": "Der er noget i luften",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .11/320. ",
    "start": 20130505075000,
    "duration": 30
  },
  "55486": {
    "title": "Der er noget i luften",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .12/320. ",
    "start": 20130505081500,
    "duration": 65
  },
  "55487": {
    "title": "Der er noget i luften",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .13/320. ",
    "start": 20130505084000,
    "duration": 25
  },
  "55488": {
    "title": "Der er noget i luften",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .14/320. ",
    "start": 20130505091000,
    "duration": 70
  },
  "55489": {
    "title": "Downton Abbey III",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .7/10. ",
    "start": 20130505101500,
    "duration": 105
  },
  "55490": {
    "title": "Downton Abbey III",
    "category": "serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .8/10. ",
    "start": 20130505110500,
    "duration": 90
  },
  "55491": {
    "title": "Kyst til kyst - Østjyllands kyst",
    "category": "entertainment, serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .2/8. ",
    "start": 20130505120500,
    "duration": 100
  },
  "55492": {
    "title": "OBS",
    "category": "news, serie",
    "start": 20130505121000,
    "duration": 5
  },
  "55493": {
    "title": "BingoBoxen",
    "category": "entertainment, serie",
    "start": 20130505122500,
    "duration": 15
  },
  "55494": {
    "title": "General Custers sidste kamp",
    "category": "movie",
    "start": 20130505144000,
    "duration": 215
  },
  "55495": {
    "title": "For godt til at være sandt",
    "category": "entertainment, serie",
    "start": 20130505150000,
    "duration": 60
  },
  "55496": {
    "title": "Miss Marple: Den gustne hest",
    "category": "movie",
    "start": 20130505163000,
    "duration": 130
  },
  "55497": {
    "title": "HåndboldSøndag: Team Tvis Holstebro-Metz Handball (k), direkte",
    "category": "sport",
    "start": 20130505183000,
    "duration": 200
  },
  "55498": {
    "title": "TV AVISEN  med Sporten og Vejret",
    "category": "news, serie",
    "start": 20130505190000,
    "duration": 70
  },
  "55499": {
    "title": "Menneskets planet",
    "category": "documentary, serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .7/8. ",
    "start": 20130505194500,
    "duration": 45
  },
  "55500": {
    "title": "Bag om Menneskets planet",
    "category": "documentary, serie",
    "episodeNumber": " .7/8. ",
    "start": 20130505200000,
    "duration": 55
  }
}
}
]
```

So the first part is correctly output with changed data.. but the submap in "programs" overwrite the data every iteration :(

Comment: Your map usage is possibly correct. Please explain more clearly what goes wrong with this code. What is your expected output and what is your actual output? Also, note that in your code you will return nonsense data if an exception occurs, since you catch the exceptions but don't re-throw them or return null.

Comment: Please also give an example of what you want your code to produce.

Comment: Yea, if i should do that, i would have to edit alot by hand.. but i want the output above, but where the sub hashmap with the key "programs" isn't the same every time.. (the different data is there, it just gets overwritten).. In the above output i have 2 "channels" of the 11 i have in total..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query for pst2 is always the same, which then of course gives the same program data every time. Did you intend to update 'time' to something for every channel? If not, how is the program related to your channel, what is their common key? This key should then be used in the pst2 SQL query to query the ones that is wanted.

Comment: Oh... doh! i feel kinda stupid for trying everything else before looking at what my query returns :s THX! i will just check if that does it.. its supposed to have an WHERE idChannel='"+rs.getString(1)+"' in it :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes you most definitely dont want to declare a new HashMap in every iteration. Declare it outside and insert the data you want accordingly

```
public static String epg() {
   Connection con = null;
   PreparedStatement pst = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   PreparedStatement pst2 = null;
   ResultSet rs2 = null;
   Date dNow = new Date();
   LinkedHashMap<String, Object> channels = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
   LinkedHashMap<Integer,Object> idProgram = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Object>();
   ...
   ...
   while (rs.next()) {
      channels.put("idChannel", rs.getString(1));
      channels.put("channelName", rs.getString(2));
      channels.put("logoPath", rs.getString(3));
      channels.put("macro", rs.getString(4))
```

Comment: Why? It looks like the map is being converted to a string before being overwritten again.

Comment: which of my maps are you referring to?

EDIT:
Yes the channels map is converted to JSON STRING

Comment: Thanks.. i changed that.. but it still doesn't change that the programs submap overwrites every iteration.. :(